# REGEXP preg_replace to Validate Model/Part Numbers

Tags: php, regex

I need a script to be able to look up part numbers in a search box using alpanumeric and "/" (slash) and "-" (dash). Here's what I have so far:

```
$query[] = "(a.name REGEXP '( )*(" . implode("|", explode(" ", preg_replace("/ +/", " ", $basic_search))) . ")( )*')";
```

Comment: What is the format of the Model/Part Numbers?

Comment: Part number formats are: ATV-51 , ATV-52H/H

Answer (score 1):

something like `/^[\w+\-\/]+$/` ? or `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]+$/` because `\w` will include `_`

Comment: Definitely the latter since it is correctly restrictive, as you mentioned (i.e., not matching `_`). +1 A couple thoughts: 1) You have an extra `+` in the first one. That will match a `+`. 2) When not used in a range context, `-` is a plain hyphen, so you don't have to escape it. Out of convention, I usually put it as the first or last character to be safe. 3) Since the delimiter `/` occurs in the expression, I'd pick a different delimiter (e.g., `#`). 4) For the sake of brevity, you may as well make it case-insensitive. `#^[a-z0-9/-]+$#i` Pretty. :-p

Comment: Can someone write the whole script out as I am a newbe? Thanks for all your help!!!